# Could the CC0's fallback license be the BSD-0? is there any difference?

Tags: cc0, 0bsd

CC0's fallback license is:

> 3. Public License Fallback.
>    Should any part of the Waiver for any reason be judged legally invalid or ineffective under applicable law, then the Waiver shall be preserved to the maximum extent permitted taking into account Affirmer's express Statement of Purpose. In addition, to the extent the Waiver is so judged Affirmer hereby grants to each affected person **a royalty-free, non transferable, non sublicensable, non exclusive, irrevocable and unconditional license to exercise Affirmer's Copyright and Related Rights in the Work (i) in all territories worldwide, (ii) for the maximum duration provided by applicable law or treaty (including future time extensions), (iii) in any current or future medium and for any number of copies, and (iv) for any purpose whatsoever, including without limitation commercial, advertising or promotional purposes (the "License").** The License shall be deemed effective as of the date CC0 was applied by Affirmer to the Work. Should any part of the License for any reason be judged legally invalid or ineffective under applicable law, such partial invalidity or ineffectiveness shall not invalidate the remainder of the License, and in such case Affirmer hereby affirms that he or she will not (i) exercise any of his or her remaining Copyright and Related Rights in the Work or (ii) assert any associated claims and causes of action with respect to the Work, in either case contrary to Affirmer's express Statement of Purpose.

BSD's 0-clause license is (without the waiver, handled separately in the CC0):

> Permission to use, copy, modify, and/or distribute this software for any purpose with or without fee is hereby granted.

Is there any difference between the CC0's license and the process of distributing individual non-transferable licenses to every affected person, compared to something like?

> 3. Public License Fallback.
>    Should any part of the Waiver for any reason be judged legally invalid or ineffective under applicable law, then the Waiver shall be preserved to the maximum extent permitted taking into account Affirmer's express Statement of Purpose. In addition, to the extent that the Waiver is so judged, the permission to use, copy, modify, and/or distribute this software for any purpose with or without fee is hereby granted.

Comment: I'm aware that the CC0 is also intended for non-code projects, and the BSD0 is for code. Consider this specifically with regard to code, or an equivalent phrasing of BSD0 with "software" exchanged for "work".